# Alfresco - Using email notification template not working properly

Tags: email, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm using out-of-the-box Alfresco 4.2.f, without customizations, and i'm trying to set the email notification whether a new document in added in a certain folder.
So i've added a rule to the folder and i've set as Perform Action "Send email" using as template "notify_user_email_it.html.ftl".
If i insert a document, i don't receive the email and here is the error in the log:

```
Expression person is undefined on line 38, column 57 in workspace://SpacesStore/55088e2c-05ac-4264-8396-ee6f3c7021ad.        
    The problematic instruction:        
    ----------        
    ==> ${person.properties.firstName} [on line 38, column 55 in workspace://SpacesStore/55088e2c-05ac-4264-8396-ee6f3c7021ad]        
    ----------
```

If i remove from the template the string ${person.properties.firstName} then the rule works properly but the mail i receive is not as expected, all the interesting informations are shown as in the original FTL. Attached the email received to understand better.

Really strange since i've not customized anything, maybe this is a BUG but i didn't find anything on JIRA...
Someone has the same behaviour? Possible work-arounds?

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to this [JIRA](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-19515), it's not really a bug it just doesn't work for the admin user.
Have you tried it with a normal user?

--- Update ---

Maybe cause it's bug or an unimplemented feature something like the following to fix it in the template:

```
<#if person??>
.... set your person properties first & lastname
<#else>
.... is sure to be admin, so set the admin
</#if>
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't find that Jira but it is really what i was talking about...i don't understand: have i create the rule as a non-admin user or i have to send the email to an address of a non-admin user?!

Comment: Rule can be created as admin, it doesn't store the person properties there. Just send the mail to anyone, only add the new document as a non-admin user. So the template will now the person object.

Comment: Don't you think you could validate the expression in your code, and if undefined, set it to generic "user" or a string?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the parameters to emails templates 
you may try with this example

```
    var template = "Data Dictionary/Email Templates/Workflow Notification/<<Your File>>.html.ftl";
    var mail = actions.create("mail");
      mail.parameters.to = "xyx@gmail.com";
       mail.parameters.subject="Hello";
        mail.parameters.text="blablabla";
        mail.parameters.template = companyhome.childByNamePath(template);
        var templateArgs = new Array();
        templateArgs['workflowTitle'] = "789789";
        templateArgs['workflowDescription'] = "879789";
        templateArgs['workflowId'] = "879789";

        var templateModel = new Array();
        templateModel['args'] = templateArgs;
       mail.parameters.template_model = templateModel;
        mail.execute(bpm_package);
```

then you can get parameters using ${args.workflowTitle} in your Email template ftl file

Comment: i am assuming that when you are sending a mail you are not passing parameter like above example;
So it may happen that you are getting the errors